# Adding quotes and commas to lines in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, parsing

I am trying to read some strings from a file that looks like this:

```
123456
password
12345678
qwerty
123456789
12345
1234
111111
1234567
dragon
...till the end
```

I want to print each line to a file with quotes and commas inserted in the following way,

```
"123456",
"password",
"12345678",
...till the end
```

I tried:

```py
fhand = open("pass.txt")

for line in fhand:
    print(f'"{line}",',end="")
```

But, this code prints quotes and commas in the wrong place:

```
"123456
","password
","12345678
","qwerty
...till the end
```

How can I remove these spurious newlines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. Each line contains a trailing newline when you first read it in. Use:

   ```py
   line.rstrip()
   ```

   rather than `line` in the format string.
2. Unrelated to the issue you're asking about, but worth pointing out: you should close the file handle using `fhand.close()` after the `for` loop. Even better, use a context manager instead, which will automatically close the file handle for you:

   ```py
   with open("pass.txt") as fhand:
       for line in fhand:
           print(f'"{line.rstrip()}",',end="")
   ```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I tried giving line.rstrip() just before the print statement but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `.rstrip()` returns a _new_ string; it doesn't modify the string in place, because strings are immutable. You need to assign the result to a variable, e.g. `line = line.rstrip()`.